# unset last item of array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

in this code i try to unset first and last item of $status array
to unset but the last item that i tried place thier pointer in $end 
not unset what can I do for this reason?

```
$item[$fieldneedle] = " node_os_disk_danger ";
$status = preg_split('/_/',$item[$fieldneedle]);
unset($status[0]);
$end = & end($status);
unset($end);
```

in this example i need `os_disk`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
array_shift($end); //removes first
array_pop($end); //removes last
```

Comment: references : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php from php.net

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode` instead of `preg_split`. It is faster.
Then you can use `array_pop` and `array_shift` to remove an item from the end and beginning of the array. Then, use `implode` to put the remaining items back together again.

A better solution would be to use `str_pos` to find the first and last `_` and use `substr` to copy the part inbetween. This will cause only one sting copy, instead of having to transform a string to array, modify that, and put the array together into a string. (Or don't you need to put them together? The 'I need 'os_disk' at the end confuses me).

Comment: tanks body but i want to now how can do this in regexp on string trim from first and last do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$item[$fieldneedle] = " node_os_disk_danger ";
$status = preg_split('/_/',$item[$fieldneedle]);
$status = array_slice($status, 1, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the result to be a string, why bother converting to a string?

```
$regex = '#^[^_]*_(.*?)_[^_]*$#';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '\\1', $string);
```

It replaces everything up to and including the first underscore character, and everything after and including the last underscore character.  Nice, easy and efficient...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use unset to remove last or any item with key

```
unset($status[0]); // removes the first item
unset($status[count($status) - 1]); // removes the last item
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex, you can do:

```
$item[$fieldneedle] = preg_replace("/^[^_]+_(.+)_[^_]+$/", "$1", $item[$fieldneedle]);
```

regex:

```
^        : begining of the string
[^_]+    : 1 or more non _ 
_        : _
(.+)     : capture 1 or more characters
_        : _
[^_]+    : 1 or more non _
$        : end of string
```

Comment: @ircmaxcell: No it is not, because the regex match, after the capture group, an `_` followed by some NON `_`