# trim from first and last of string how do it

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unset last item of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668997/unset-last-item-of-array)

i want do this without of expload, array_pop and array_shift

```
$item[$fieldneedle] = " node_os_disk_danger ";
$objectName = preg_split('/_/',$item[$fieldneedle]);
$objectName == "os_disk";
```

in this example i need `os_disk`

Comment: Exact duplicate of [unset last item of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668997/unset-last-item-of-array) - Please don't re-post questions.  Edit or add comments to your original question.  (And there are answers on that question that solve the problem you're asking here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?:^.*?_)(.*)(?:_.*$)/
```

..will only capture the `os_disk` part