# Deletion of element on a string not working, after conversion to an array

Tags: php

The code below explains how to delete an element by using the unset function,
I have used a string and converted the string into an array,
Now trying to delete the first and last element.
But the elements do not get deleted.
Help would be grateful

```
<?php
$string="Cupid";  //orginal string
$stringmod= str_split($string);  //converted the string to an array
$length= count($stringmod); //length of the string
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) 
{

    if($i == 0 || $i == $length-1) //condition to be executed
    {
        
        unset($stringmod[$i]); //delete elements
    
    }
    
}
print_r($stringmod);
?>
```

Comment: change `length` to `$length`... and turn error reporting ON

Comment: Instead of iterating through the array, you might find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669025/2453432

Comment: The length is a type mistake sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code, you are missing *$* before *length* in the loop.

Despite that: there is no need to loop through the array - you can directly address the elements. The following will work:

```
<?php
   $string="Cupid";
   $stringmod= str_split($string);
   unset($stringmod[count($stringmod)-1]);
   unset($stringmod[0]);
   print_r($stringmod);
?>
```

The functions array_pop and array_shift will do the same (remove last/first element from your array). They are better if you want to do it again later in the code (the PHP is using associative arrays, so $stringmod[0] is the first element only in the beginning - when you remove it, there is no longer $stringmod[0], so executing unset($stringmod[0]) twice will not remove two "first" elements, but only one). So probably the best answer in this case is:

```
<?php
   $string="Cupid";
   $stringmod= str_split($string);
   array_pop($stringmod);
   array_shift($stringmod);
   print_r($stringmod);
?>
```

P.S. Based on the comment from Andrew below my answer, you can also do reordering with array_values() function or remove elements with array_splice() (which will also reorder). Personally I do not like to use them because they take resources and when possible I do not rely on that the arrays are with sorted indexes of magic numbers :)

Comment: To circumnavigate the issue with `unset` upsetting the index, you can use `array_values` to reorder the keys.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Using array_splice is also an option for removing elements - it also reorders, so we can for example remove twice the first element by array_splice($stringmod,0,1). But these functions take resources. Personally I do not like to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`array_shift` will remove the first element from an array, re-indexing numerical keys.

`array_pop` will remove the last.

```
$string="Cupid";  //orginal string
$stringmod= str_split($string); 

array_shift($stringmod);
array_pop($stringmod);

print_r($stringmod);
```

If you want to do it via a loop, as per [@jibsteroos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9583205/jibsteroos) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633409/deletion-of-element-on-a-string-not-working-after-conversion-to-an-array/62633794#comment110762679_62633409), you are pretty much there, you just need to correctly reference the test counter in the `for` loop.